# pasar el nombre de un archivo en PHP

Tags: php, web

una duda, espero puedan apoyarme, realice una un procedimiento en php donde a través de un botón genero un archivo de excel y lo almaceno, y lo nombro con datos de lo que guardo dentro del excel, terminando este proceso regreso a mi portal web y tengo un botón de descarga para obtener el archivo creado, pero no se como pasarle a mi codigo de descarga el nombre con el cual guarde el archivo, el código de descarga lo tengo en otro archivo php

Comment: Por que no declaras el nombre de tu archivo en una variable y lo mandas llamar en el **header**, **header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$variable_nombre."".xls");**

Comment: También podrías evitar un par de pasos, al momento de hacer click en el botón que genera el excel, este se genere y posteriormente lo lances para descargar de manera automática, sin necesidad de recurrir a otro botón para descargar.  En caso de que requieras esa opción como explicas quizás podrías guardar el nombre del archivo y la ruta en una tabla en la base de datos y esos datos pasarlos al botón como parámetros para descargarlo.